# jQuery não funciona em App Electron

Tags: jquery, electron

Estou criando um aplicativo *Electron* apenas estudo, só que estou encontrando um problema.

Criei uma página *html* simples, utilizando o framework *Bootstrap 4.0*, nela coloquei apenas um menu.

> **index.html**

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
          <!--a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a-->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Arquivos</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Configurações</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          <strong>wmsouza</strong>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                      </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                          <div class="navbar-login">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                                      <p class="text-center">
                                          <i class="fa fa-user icon-size" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-8">
                                      <p class="text-left"><strong>Wéllingthon Motta</strong></p>
                                      <p class="text-left small">wellingthonmotta@email.com</p>
                                      <p class="text-left">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">Atualizar dados</a>
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                              <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
                                  <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                                          <p>
                                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Sair</a>
                                          </p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Adicione nela os *scripts* necessários.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Feito assim, ao abrir o arquivo *index.html* no navegador, funciona perfeitamente.

[image: Página funcionando no Chrome]

Mais ao executar no *aplicativo*, o método *dropdown* não funciona e retorna erro no console falando que o *Bootstrap* necessita do *jQuery*.

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6
>   (anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

[image: Erro no console]

Porém na aba *Network*, mostra que o *jQuery* foi carregado.

[image: Aba network status 200]

O que pode estar acontecendo ?

Comment: Já experimentaste com o jQuery 2? O 3 é uma versão muito reduzida, talve zlhe falte algum método.

Comment: Tentei com a versão 2, também não deu certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o Eletron usa o node.js ou seja o jQuery acaba trabalhando como se não estivesse rodando em um "browser", então ao invés do jQuery ficar acessivel no escopo do `window.` ele acaba ficando só acessível no escopo do `global.` ou apenas usando `require()`, isto por causa deste trecho:

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

    // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
    // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
    // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
    // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
    // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
    // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
    // See ticket #14549 for more info.
    module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
} else {
    factory( global );
}
```

Creio que ao adicionar via `<script>` você já terá disponível nos módulos, então pode adicionar assim ao `window.`:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

No entanto você também pode optar por baixar os recursos e usa-los assim:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./caminho/pasta/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js');
```

> `./caminho/pasta/js` é apenas um exemplo

Ao invés de usar os CDNs, ainda mais sendo um aplicativo talvez seja interessante ter os recursos *offline*